# Swallow doesnotrecognizeselector exception from an NSInvocation forwardInvocation call

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, nsinvocation, message-forwarding

I have an object which is forwarding receiving messages. It does not implement forwarding them to other objects using `forwardInvocation`. However, `methodSignatureForSelector` will not always return a valid method signature at certain times because of the way the program is organized. How can I swallow the exception generated from the missing method signature? Overriding `doesNotRecognizeSelector` does not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must generate some signature (even if a dummy one, e.g. `v@:`, a signature of a method that returns `void` and takes no arguments) and then remember to do nothing when it gets to `forwardInvocation:`.

Comment: Could you post some example code for this... trying hard to do the same thing.

Comment: @unmircea: Basically, in your `methodSignatureForSelector:` method, if you decide to swallow the call for a selector, but don't have the signature, return `[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@:"]`. Then, in your `forwardInvocation:` method, check the same condition on the selector for swallowing that you used in `methodSignatureForSelector:`, and if it is met, simply return and don't process further.